# Объект класса внутри другого класса

Tags: c++

Предположим я создаю класс А с какими-то данными и конструктором чтобы эти данные ввести.
Затем я создаю другой класс B, в котором мне нужно создать поле типа A. Но возникает проблема - я не могу нормально вызвать конструктор A, чтобы проинициализировать его данные. Пробовал так:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    A(int _a, int _b): a(_a), b(_b) {}

};

class B
{
private:
    A test(5,5); //Не работает
    A test2; 
public:
    B(int m, int n)
    { //Если сделать так то ругается на этой строчке
        A tmp(m,n);
        test2 = tmp;
    }
};
```

Не подскажите, как нужно поступить в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 4):

Все банально и просто:

```
class B{
  ...
  A test;
  A test2;
  ...
  B(int m, int n) : test(5,5), test2(6,6){
   ...
  }
};
```

Comment: Опередил на несколько секунд:). А вам, уважаемый @vacsus, не помешает на столе книжка Страуструпа, или хотя бы искать в гугл перед тем, как задавать вопрос.

Comment: Странно, впервые вижу, чтобы @ХэшКод действовал анонимно: я комментарий ответом не делал, и истории изменений у ответа нет, хотя я несколько раз комментарий редактировал. Обычно, во время такого преобразования, редакции комментариев переходят в редакции ответа, а здесь - получилось так, будто @ХэшКод просто создал ответ от моего имени.

Comment: Сделал общим, и сразу вся история появилась :) Видимо, это был баг.

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с С++11 можно инициализировать члены прямо в теле класса:

```
class B
{
private:
    A test{5,5}; // Фигурные скобки вместо круглых
    A test2; 
public:
    // Список инициализации, если надо передать параметры из конструктора
    B(int m, int n) : test2(m, n) {}
};
```